# Do you need to wait for completion on a TPL Dataflow DataflowBlock.NullTarget<T>

Tags: task-parallel-library, dataflow

Questions like this one:

[TPL Dataflow, how to forward items to only one specific target block among many linked target blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599190/tpl-dataflow-how-to-forward-items-to-only-one-specific-target-block-among-many)

propose using the DataflowBlock.NullTarget{T} to discard items from a pipeline, e.g.

```
forwarder.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<SomeType>());
```

However, if you use NullTarget like this, how do you wait for Completion? Would it not be better to create a discard block:

```
ITargetBlock<SomeType> discard = DataflowBlock.NullTarget<SomeType>();
forwarder.LinkTo(discard);
```

and wait for completion on this? i.e.

```
discard.Completion.Wait()
```

Or do you not need to wait for completion of a "NullTarget" block, i.e. is it simply throw away and forget?

Comment: Why would you *want* to wait for it? That block doesn't do any processing so I don't see any reason why would you want to wait for it.

Comment: Because I've built a pipeline, and in order to wait for completion of the pipeline, I need to Wait() on all the endpoints. These look to me like endpoints (and they do have a Completion property).

Comment: Ok, I've had a look inside the dataflow library, and apparently the Completion of this returns a TaskCompletionSource<VoidResult>().Task. Guess I'm reading up on TaskCompletionSource now! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't documented, but based on my tests, the `Completion` of a `NullTarget` will *never* complete, even after you `Complete()` or `Fault()` it.

What this means is that you can't wait on the completion of `NullTarget` blocks, because the waiting would never end.

Comment: Internally, DataFlow even calls this "NeverCompletingTask"... so I guess that settles it. Cheers.

Comment: Ug. I had tried to use NullTarget as a no-op replacement for a specific ActionBlock in my workflow, but then waiting on that block fails. Now I know why. Seems like this is an area of improvement for a future release.